# Position div based upon another that has absolute position

Tags: css, flexbox

I have [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5xkezz1z/)

In the fiddle, I would like to position the green box in the center of the large box. Also, I would like to position the red box after the green box, on a horizontal line, [like in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfytwgas/1/)(but I don't want to specify a margin in pixels, I want the position of the red box to depend on the one of the green box).

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  align-self: center
}

#div2 {
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  align-self: center
}

*/
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

The position of the green box is a given(I can't change `position:absolute`). How can I place the red box immediately after it?

Comment: Could you show us some image how do you want it to be ? What do you mean by: "_position the red box after the green box, on a horizontal line_"?

Comment: If you disable the `position: absolute` setting it appears to be what you're asking for, however as you already have that I'm assuming it's there for a reason. As @Krusader asked for, it'd be useful to have an image showing your expected result.

Comment: If you don't need the absolute positioning, remove them and change `flex-direction:column;` to `flex-direction:row;`

Comment: I updated my question with another fiddle @Krusader.

Comment: @ Paulie_D then should I duplicate the code by putting it in both the fiddle and the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to match the *red* + *green* items sum width.

The added `left/right/transform` properties are needed to center the absolute positioned *green* element cross browsers.

Stack snippet

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#parent::before {
  content: '';
  width: 60%;                           /*  sum of green and red  */
  height: 60%;                          /*  sum of green and red  */
}

#div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;                            /*  added  */
  top: 50%;                             /*  added  */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);      /*  added  */
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! What does `#parent::before` mean?

Comment: @octavian It creates a _pseudo element_, which one can use instead of  adding an extra element in the markup.

Comment: @octavian Updated my answer with this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: I just realized that the green `div` doesn't have an `absolute` position. I can't change that. Would this work with an `absolute` position for the green box?

Comment: @octavian Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! How coame `#parent::before` has an impact on `div2` rather than `parent`?

Comment: @octavian Because the pseudo `::before` behaves and acts as a child of the `#parent`, hence participate as if you would have added an extra element in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?:

https://jsfiddle.net/5xkezz1z/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
#parent div{
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  width: 35%;
}
#div1 {background:green}
#div2 {background:red}
```

or something like this?:

https://jsfiddle.net/5xkezz1z/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
#parent .blocks{
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
}
#parent .blocks div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#div1 {background:green}
#div2 {background:red}
```

Comment: Neither unfortunately. The position of the green box has to be central and `absolute`. I can't change that. How can I put the red box immediately after it, like here https://jsfiddle.net/bfytwgas/1/?